# iOS universal app - Blank white screen on startup

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I have created a universal app and it shows a blank white screen on startup. The initial view controller does not load. I have done trying all the alternatives suggested :

> 1. Set launch image source to Asset Catalog in General settings and removing launch screen file. (This shows a black screen)
> 2. Set Main interface (It was already set)
> 3. No missing constraint in the view.
> 4. Set `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
> 5. Set the ViewController as Initial view controller in Storyboard (It was already set).

How I might get out of this trouble ?
I am adding the screenshot of my project settings just in case.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my initial view controller in storyboard :

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot showing your initial view controller in your Main.storyboard?

Comment: @nishithSingh : Added

Comment: Can you check if your Main.Storyboard has been added in your info.plist as well under "Main storyboard file base name"?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. Actually it is nothing wrong with what I am doing. The issue is in viewDidLoad code :

```
view_padding = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 30))
username.leftView = view_padding
username.leftViewMode = .Always

password.leftView = view_padding
password.leftViewMode = .Always
```

Not sure why but will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Update the Launch Images in General Settings**

Set the "Launch screen file" is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The images showed in `launch.storyboard` should locate in the project directly, or a folder in the project.

Use the image as `xxx.png`, then the IOS splash screen is normal.

---

The images showed in `launch.storyboard` is not seen for splash screen, when located in `Assets.xcassets/xxx.imageset`